# Can't install WiFi drivers for Broadcom AP6255

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, broadcom

i'm trying to configure WiFi on my Mini PC Beelink BT3 PRO that has a Broadcom AP6255. 
I tried many of the proposed solutions online but with no success. The interface just does not show up.
This is the result of wireless-info.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 22 Aug 2019 14:20 CEST +0200

Booted last: 22 Aug 2019 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /home/kofm/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

./wireless-info: line 192: rfkill: command not found

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

brcmsmac              565248  0
cordic                 16384  1 brcmsmac
bcma                   57344  1 brcmsmac
mac80211              782336  1 brcmsmac
snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651    20480  0
brcmfmac              315392  0
brcmutil               16384  2 brcmfmac,brcmsmac
cfg80211              622592  3 brcmfmac,mac80211,brcmsmac
snd_soc_rt5651         90112  2 snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5651
snd_soc_core          241664  3 snd_soc_rt5651,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform
snd_pcm                98304  6 snd_soc_rt5651,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5651,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.135/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'enp1s0' [IF1]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.135 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    None found.

Running:

    None found.

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager is not installed (package "network-manager").

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: No such file or directory

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

No NetworkManager profiles found.

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses: [ 192.168.1.135/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8,4.4.4.4]

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Rome (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[brcmsmac]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw
firmware:       brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     823188596714968C60828FF
depends:        mac80211,bcma,brcmutil,cfg80211,cordic
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           brcmsmac
vermagic:       4.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     F4DB57748318105D28C557A
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           bcma
vermagic:       4.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     FDB9FBFE52A6192B8CC9B9E
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[brcmfmac]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11 wireless LAN fullmac driver.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4373-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4373.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43569.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43242a.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43236b.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365c-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4359-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
srcversion:     DDCAB95D12632C778BDAC0E
depends:        brcmutil,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           brcmfmac
vermagic:       4.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           txglomsz:Maximum tx packet chain size [SDIO] (int)
parm:           debug:Level of debug output (int)
parm:           p2pon:Enable legacy p2p management functionality (int)
parm:           feature_disable:Disable features (int)
parm:           alternative_fw_path:Alternative firmware path (string)
parm:           fcmode:Mode of firmware signalled flow control (int)
parm:           roamoff:Do not use internal roaming engine (int)

[brcmutil]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11n wireless LAN driver utilities.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
srcversion:     418AE02D2004334CCEFD1AA
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           brcmutil
vermagic:       4.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     34711E0450EF391760E5E7A
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-58-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

grep: /sys/module/brcmfmac/parameters/alternative_fw_path: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/brcmfmac/parameters/debug: Permission denied
grep: /sys/module/brcmfmac/parameters/roamoff: Permission denied
[brcmfmac]

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mdadm.conf]
options md_mod start_ro=1

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    9.895198] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth SDIO driver ver 0.1
[    9.959830] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd failed with error -2
[    9.959843] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd not found
[   10.097059] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin for chip 0x004345(17221) rev 0x000006
[   10.830953] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: quirk DMIC_MAP enabled
[   10.830959] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: quirk DMIC enabled
[   10.830962] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: quirk MCLK_EN enabled
[   10.874739] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> media-cpu-dai mapping ok
[   10.874822] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: snd-soc-dummy-dai <-> deepbuffer-cpu-dai mapping ok
[   10.874986] bytcr_rt5651 bytcr_rt5651: rt5651-aif1 <-> ssp2-port mapping ok
[   10.899701] input: bytcr-rt5651 Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/808622A8:00/bytcr_rt5651/sound/card1/input10
[   11.688608] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[   11.688900] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   13.128109] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50 (repeated 3 times)
[   16.439948] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link up
[   16.439969] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0: link becomes ready
[   30.059028] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp1s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:24:f5:a2:00:89:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3435 PROTO=2 
[  155.311982] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp1s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:24:f5:a2:00:89:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3437 PROTO=2 
[  279.920593] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp1s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:24:f5:a2:00:89:26:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=3439 PROTO=2 

########## wireless info END ############
```

The output of `dmesg | grep -i sdio`

```
[    3.699477] mmc1: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDIO card at address 0001
[    9.911273] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth SDIO driver ver 0.1
[   10.107255] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin for chip 0x004345(17221) rev 0x000006
[   13.143419] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   14.160121] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   15.164314] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Other requested outputs:

```
$ dmesg | grep brcm
[    9.767200] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd failed with error -2
[    9.767210] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd not found
[   10.107255] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin for chip 0x004345(17221) rev 0x000006
[   10.111627] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   13.143419] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   14.160121] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[   15.164314] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

I contacted the Beelink product support and they sent me some drivers, but I can't figure how to install it.

The drivers seem a copy of this repo https://github.com/linux-rockchip/linux-rockchip/tree/mirror/stable-3.0/drivers/net/wireless/rkwifi/bcmdhd

Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **ubuntu-live** desktop, install Wi-Fi was enabled without any problem, after installing Ubuntu 18 server Wi-Fi did not work.

The solution was found on below link and its instructions for enabling Wi-Fi.

https://medium.com/home-wireless/run-headless-ubuntu-on-an-atom-z8350-pc-48df5645bba

Also cross-posting the solution here:

Create the file `/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt` and reboot the system. The Wi-Fi interface `wlan0` can now be configured with either `netplan`, `systemd` or `/etc/network/interfaces` style.

```
/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt
```

```
#AP6255_NVRAM_V1.0_29052015

NVRAMRev=$Rev: 498373 $
sromrev=11
vendid=0x14e4
devid=0x43ab
manfid=0x2d0
prodid=0x06e4
macaddr=00:90:4c:c5:12:38
nocrc=1
boardtype=0x6e4
boardrev=0x1304
xtalfreq=37400
#boardflags: 5GHz eTR switch by default
#2.4GHz eTR switch by default
#bit1 for btcoex
boardflags=0x00080201
boardflags2=0x40000000
boardflags3=0x48200100
rxgains2gelnagaina0=0
rxgains2gtrisoa0=0
rxgains2gtrelnabypa0=0
rxgains5gelnagaina0=0
rxgains5gtrisoa0=0
rxgains5gtrelnabypa0=0
rxchain=1
txchain=1
aa2g=1
aa5g=1
tssipos5g=1
tssipos2g=1
femctrl=0
AvVmid_c0=0,157,1,126,1,126,1,126,1,126
pa2ga0=-112,6296,-662
pa2ga1=-165,3699,-515
pa5ga0=-143,6016,-683,-141,6013,-678,-137,5988,-670,-136,5982,-670
pa5ga1=-161,3544,-499,-166,3543,-497,-169,3569,-497,-171,3598,-498
itrsw=1
pdoffset2g40ma0=10
pdoffset40ma0=0xaaaa
pdoffset80ma0=0xaaaa
extpagain5g=2
extpagain2g=2
tworangetssi2g=1
tworangetssi5g=1
# LTECX flags
# WCI2
ltecxmux=0
ltecxpadnum=0x0504
ltecxfnsel=0x22
ltecxgcigpio=0x32

maxp2ga0=64
ofdmlrbw202gpo=0x0033
dot11agofdmhrbw202gpo=0x1553
mcsbw202gpo=0x99355533

maxp5ga0=80,82,76,77

mcsbw205glpo=0x99755000
mcsbw205gmpo=0x9df55000
mcsbw205ghpo=0x99855000

mcsbw405glpo=0xb8555000
mcsbw405gmpo=0xed955000
mcsbw405ghpo=0xd9755000

mcsbw805glpo=0xc8555000
mcsbw805gmpo=0xe9555000
mcsbw805ghpo=0xd9555000

swctrlmap_2g=0x00040004,0x00020002,0x00040004,0x010a02,0x1ff
swctrlmap_5g=0x00100010,0x00200020,0x00100010,0x010a02,0x2f4
swctrlmapext_5g=0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x000000,0x000
swctrlmapext_2g=0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x000000,0x000

vcodivmode=1
deadman_to=481500000
ed_thresh2g=-54
ed_thresh5g=-54

#muxenab=0x10
sd_gpout=0
sd_gpval=0

ccode=CN
regrev=38
```

Answer (score 2):

Your device is almost certainly this:

```
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4345*
```

This is from the alias field of the driver *brcmfmac* which loads on boot according to your dmesg. We get the clue from your dmesg:

```
brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin for chip 0x004345(17221) rev 0x000006
```

The only '4345' alias is as I quoted above.

Various sources suggest, as you included in your question, that the driver *bcmdhd* is preferred. However, no recent version of the driver can be found to compile and try. The last update to the code you referenced was updated six years ago. It will not compile on any recent kernel.

Finally, the usually reliable Wikidevi reports:  https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Talk:Linux_Wi-Fi_device_entries#02d0_-_Broadcom

> 02d0:4345 - BCM4345 (old ver BCM43455) - Unsupported SDIO ID:
>   SD\VID_02D0&PID_4345

In conclusion, although *brcmfmac* loads and loads firmware, it doesn't drive the device. I regret to agree; the device is unsupported.

**FOOTNOTE**: I have included my research notes here as I hope it will help others who are searching.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your efforts.

Comment: BCM43455 is the newer version of BCM4345. On a Wintel MiniPC (AMI, T3 MRD, Atom x5-Z8350) running Ubuntu 18.04, after following steps in another answer by Sascha, this device is actually supported. In my case dmesg reports (brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6).

Answer (score 1):

The missing NVRAM definition file is board-dependent. You can see that the [kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/brcm) firmware includes this file for some boards. We should send pull requests to support other boards. Note that BCM43455 is a newer version of BCM4345, also known as AP6255; I happen to have the older version and is supported by brcmfmac driver.

On a Wintel MiniPC (AMI, T3 MRD, Atom x5-Z8350 [CherryTrail]) running Windows 10, the file is found at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\4345r6nvram.txt` (file contents turned out to be identical to the one in [Sascha's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1211986/527764)) and can be copied to Linux, then do:

```
sudo cp 4345r6nvram.txt /lib/firmware/brcm/
cd /lib/firmware/brcm/
ln -s 4345r6nvram.txt brcmfmac43455-sdio.txt
sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

Answer (score 0):

I am 0 in Linux and in fact 1st day with MintOS however was able to find my way on this issue - huge hint given by @milpita

Find the following files online or in the Windows Driver folders:

- File 1: `4345r6nvram.txt`
- File 2: `bcm943341wlagb.txt`

All we have to do is copy the above files to: `/lib/firmware/brcm/`, using elevated permissions (for example you can use `sudo -H nautilus` - make sure you close it after moving the files). I know nothing about the command line :-))